# Why does Pandas change the day and month in places?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have encountered this problem, and I would like to understand why Pandas changes the month and day in places.

The data is shown at the top as it looks before formatting in DateTime, and at the bottom, respectively, after formatting.

can you explain to me why this is happening or how to fix it?

Thank you all in advance for the answer!

P.S I tried to format the data without "strftime" still swaps the day and month

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`08.09.2016` is an ambiguous format (depending on the locale, it is interpreted as Aug 9 or Sep 8). By default, Pandas parses this as `%m.%d.%Y`. To force parsing as `%d.%m.%Y`, use `dayfirst=True`.

```
In [6]: pd.to_datetime('08.09.2016').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
Out[6]: '09.08.2016'

In [7]: pd.to_datetime('08.09.2016', dayfirst=True).strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
Out[7]: '08.09.2016'
```

Note that `21.09.2018` is unambiguous, since `21` cannot be a month.